# The function 'edge' is not supported for standalone code generation

Tags: matlab, simulink, matlab-cvst, edge-detection

I am trying to use the edge(I,'sobel') method inside a Matlab function block in Simulink(MATLAB 2013a). When I try to compile, I get the error "The function 'edge' is not supported for standalone code generation". 
I know there is an edge detector block , but I want to call the function with in the Matlab function block. How to get around this.

Comment: I don't know what you intend to do. Maybe Matlab Builder NE is a solution, output is a .net DLL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Computer Vision System toolbox you can use `vision.EdgeDetector` System object. If you have edge detector block then you already have this toolbox. This object supports code generation. The default edge detector method it uses is 'Sobel'. When you generate code for this object remember to set all properties using constructor arguments. You may not be able to change properties after construction when generating code.

```
edgeObj = vision.EdgeDetector;
edges = step(edgeObj, inputImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to declare the function as an extrinsic:

coder.extrinsic('edge');

then it should work for simulation but not code generation.