# MATLAB Coder Error: The function 'bwboundaries' is not supported for standalone code generation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-coder

I want to run MATLAB 2015b algorithm on Android device through NDK. So I need a standalone c code from algorithm. I used Matlab Coder for this, But I get this error:

> The function 'bwboundaries' is not supported for standalone code generation. See the documentation for coder.extrinsic to learn how you can use this function in simulation.`
>   I used this function in this way:

```
[B,L]=bwboundaries(h1);
```

the h1 is an 280*500 logical array which comes from a Black & White image.
I searched and found this list: [Functions and Objects Supported for C and C++ Code Generation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--alphabetical-list.html)
As we see there the `bwboundaries` declared in the list:

> bwboundaries :
>
> The conn and options arguments must be compile-time constants and the return value A can only be a full matrix, not a sparse matrix.
>
> If you choose the generic MATLAB Host Computer target platform, generated code uses a precompiled, platform-specific shared library.
>
> MATLAB Function Block support: No.

I don't understand it!! How should I use this function to have its c code?
OR Is there any function to use instead?

I see this SO questions which didn't help me:
[q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25527248/matlab-coder-num2str-not-supported) [q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23229744/how-to-convert-matlab-function-pchip-to-c-code-with-matlab-coder) [q3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19641024/the-function-edge-is-not-supported-for-standalone-code-generation)

Comment: What version of MATLAB? The online documentation only ever refers to the most recent version. Check the [documentation archives](http://www.mathworks.com/help/doc-archives.html) for your specific version

Comment: @ Suever sorry! My version is 2015b.

Comment: If you had clicked on the link I provided above you would see that [it is not supported in your version of MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2015b/coder/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--alphabetical-list.html)

Comment: which version support it?

Comment: Version r2016a. The current version corresponding to the documentation you linked

Comment: thank you Suever. write an answer to mark it.